# Recorrer arraylist<String> y comparar subcadenas si son iguales o similares

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist

Mi pregunta es **como puedo comparar las cadenas que tengo dentro de un `arraylist<String>` de forma que me muestre las que están repetidas?** PERO estas cadenas son irregulares, por ej: Tengo los siguientes archivos en una carpeta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un metodo que levanta todo lo que se encuentra en la carpeta y lo carga en un arraylist.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivos = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Array1 = new ArrayList<>();

public void buscarArchivo(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
        File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
        if (archivo != null) {
            arrayArchivos.clear();
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
            for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                    buscarArchivo(archivo[i]);
                } else {
                    String file = archivo[i].getName();
//                    Quitamos la extencion
                    arrayArchivos.add(file.substring(0, file.length() - 4));
                }
            }
//            Llamamos al metodo evaluarNombre.
            evaluarNombre();
        }
    }
```

En mi metodo **evaluarNombre()** tengo:

```
public void evaluarNombre() {

        if (arrayArchivos != null) {
            for (String arrayArchivo : arrayArchivos) {
//              Quitamos los espacios al principio y al final con trim(), luego mostramos solo letras.
                String b = arrayArchivo.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").trim();
//              Quitamos los espacios innecesarios para dejar solo un espacio entre letras.
                String d = b.replaceAll(" +", " ");
//              Añadimos a un nuevo array todos los String filtrados.
                Array1.add(d);

            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontro ningun archivo.");
        }
        contar(Array1);
    }
```

En el método **contar(Array1)**

```
private void contar(ArrayList<String> arraStrings) {
//        Declaramos un contador.
        int c = 0;
        if (arraStrings != null) {
//           Nos posicionamos en un elemento y recorremos el resto comparando.
            for (int i = 0; i < arraStrings.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arraStrings.size(); j++) {
//                Si los nombres de las cadenas son iguales, el contador se ingrementa.
                    if (arraStrings.get(i).substring(0, arraStrings.get(i).lastIndexOf(" ")).equals(arraStrings.get(j).substring(0, arraStrings.get(j).lastIndexOf(" ")))) {
                        c++;
                    }
                }

//            Evaluo que el contador sea mayor a 1.
                if (c > 1) {
                    System.out.println("El archivo '" + arraStrings.get(i) + "' Se repite " + c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Array vacio");
        }
    }
```

Sa salida que obtengo es:

**El archivo 'Maluma Corazon Dexter Remix Global Music' Se repite 2**

**El archivo 'Maluma Corazon Dexter Remix Global Music' Se repite 2**

**El archivo 'Agapornis Mueve la Cintura Dexter Remix Global Music' Se repite 2**

**El archivo 'Lali Una Mas Dexter Remix Global Music' Se repite 3**

**El archivo 'Lali Una Mas Dexter Remix Global Music' Se repite 3**

**El archivo 'Charlie Puth Attention David Guetta Vs Dexter Remix Global Music' Se repite 3**

Como se ve en la imagen, me marca archivos que no estan repetidos, como por ej:

**Agapornis Mueve la Cintura Dexter Remix Global Music**

**Charlie Puth Attention David Guetta Vs Dexter Remix Global Music**

Sin embargo me los cuenta. Al igual que el archivo

**Ozuna Ft Zion & Lennox Egoista Dexter Remix (Global Music11) copia**

**SI** se encuentra repetido pero con la diferencia que tiene la palabra **copia**, me seria de gran ayuda su colaboración para poder identificar que estoy haciendo mal, desde ya gracias.

Comment: Es curioso que el número de repeticiones solo aumente según se avanza en la lista, ¿no crees? En todo caso, te recomiendo que depures y que mires qué valores van tomando las variables en cada caso...

Comment: No pondria esto como una respuesta pero esto me ayudo a que no se repitieran valores de un array en una lista, supongo que puedes usarlo a la inversa  y los que se repitan agregarlos a otro array:                                            
"El método indexOf comprueba si un elemento existe en el array. Si lo encuentra devuelve el índice del elemento y si no devuelve -1. Por eso si el resultado es menor que 0 es que el elemento no existe". – Asier Villanueva. osea que si te da 0 es que ya existe (la sintaxis: if (valores.indexOf(Sector) < 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tienes que definir que criterio usarás para determinar que 2 cadenas estan "repetidas".

- Son realmente iguales: `cadena1.equals(cadena2)` retorna true
- Una contiene a la otra: `cadena1.contains(cadena2) || cadena2.contains(cadena1)` retorna true
- Algún criterio de distancia de edición o similitud: como los implementados en este repositorio https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity

Luego que definas eso debes prestar atención a que cada cadena de texto debe tener su propio contador de repeticiones:

```
private void contar(ArrayList<String> arraStrings) {
    if (arraStrings != null) {
// Nos posicionamos en un elemento y recorremos el resto comparando.
        for (int i = 0; i < arraStrings.size(); i++) {
// Declaramos un contador.
            int c = 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arraStrings.size(); j++) {
// Si los nombres de las cadenas son iguales, el contador se ingrementa.
                if (cadenasIguales(arraStrings.get(i), arraStrings.get(j))) {
                    c++;
                }
            }

// Evaluo que el contador sea mayor a 1.
            if (c > 1) {
                System.out.println("El archivo '" + arraStrings.get(i) + "' Se repite " + c);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Array vacio");
    }
}

private boolean cadenasIguales(String cadena1, String cadena2) {
//logica original
//    return cadena1.substring(0, cadena1.lastIndexOf(" ")).equals(cadena2.substring(0, cadena2.lastIndexOf(" ")));
    return cadena1.contains(cadena2) || cadena2.contains(cadena1);
}
```

Por último, el código anterior va a reportar distintas repeticiones para cada cadena repetida:

- abc
- abc copia
- abc copia2

`"abc"` se repite 2 veces mientras que `"abc copia"` se repite 1 vez.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar un string que te guarde el string de la posición del array en la que esté y, dentro de esa posición recorres con otro for el arraylist nuevamente y comparas para ver si se parece a alguna otra.